# Multiple select to Query builder Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I do a lot searching on database
I would be grateful for your corrections.

How realize search from multiple choice in select blood[]?

form.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open(['url'=>'search/go','method'=>'post','id'=>'search']) }}
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    {{ Form::label('search_name', 'City') }}
    {{ Form::text('search_name','',['id'=>'search_name', 'class'=>'form-control col-md-3']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    {{ Form::label('blood', 'Blood') }}
    {{ Form::select('blood[]', array_merge(array('default' => 'Please Select'),$blood), 'default',array('multiple')) }}
</div>
{{ Form::submit('Go',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

search.js

```
$('#search').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
            url: '/search/go',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: formData,
        }).done(
            function(data)
            {
                $('table').html(data);
            }
        );
    });
```

SearchController.php

How correctly search from databese my blood fields

```
public function search(){
        $get = Input::get();
        if($get['search_name']){
            $donors = Search::where('city','LIKE','%'.$get['search_name'].'%');
        }


        if($get['blood'] != 'default'){
            $blood = Search::distinct()->lists('blood');
            $bl = $blood[$get['blood']];
            $donors = $donors->where('blood','=',$bl);
        }

        $donors = $donors->get();
        return View::make('search.search',compact('donors'));
    }
```

Comment: `$get = Input::get();` should be `$get = Input::all()`. Also by chaining `$donors->where` conditions, you are trying to get a donor living in X city with blood types `X`, `Y`, `Z`. I believe what you need here is `$donors->whereOr` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really understand the question, but maybe this what you're looking for http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/. There are a few alternatives but this one's the best I've found.